# Proof $\Delta \vec{E} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial ^2\vec{E}}{\partial t^2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

Here's what I'm doing, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Furthermore, I think $c^2$ is the  speed of light, however is $c^2 = (\mu_0\epsilon_0)^{-1}$ as follow?

$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec{E}) = \nabla \times(- \frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t})$$

$$\nabla(\nabla \cdot\vec{E})- \nabla^2\vec{E} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla \times \vec{B})$$

$$-\nabla^2\vec{E} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t} + \mu_0\vec{J})$$

$$\nabla^2\vec{E} = \frac{\partial^2\vec{E}}{\partial t^2}\mu_0\epsilon_0$$

$$\Delta \vec{E} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial ^2\vec{E}}{\partial t^2}$$

Comment: you might want to call it a derivation, not a proof. And yes, in your system of units, $\varepsilon_0\mu_0=c^{-2}$.

Comment: There was a typo in the speed of light relation (I fixed it). Your derivation seems to be correct. You can compare it with WikiPedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation